# Best sourcesafe system for iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, version-control, backup, cvs

which is best sourcesafe system for iphone xcode on backup and proper check-in & check-out on codes

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it appears that you're using 'sourcesafe' as a generic term for version control.

for version control of xcode projects:

i have used cvs, subversion, and now git (also serving as a front-end for other systems).

git is my first choice (it is distributed, and quite fast).

svn (subversion) is my second choice - you may have more coworkers/projects which prefer svn, although git may also be used as a svn client.

lastly - i prefer using dedicated visual clients over xcode... xcode seems to be busy doing other things. it is usually faster to disable vc in xcode, and hop to a terminal or other client while xcode builds/debugs/updates indexes, etc.

Comment: Thanks justin and here we using dynamsoft for .net json and it is possible to use same for xcode iphone sdk

Comment: @Sathish you're welcome. it appears that SourceAnywhere for VSS is also available as a standalone client on OS X: `http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/SAW_Overview.aspx` however, i don't know anybody who's using it for iphone development.

Answer (score 4):

XCode supports CVS, Perforce and SVN out of the box. Out of the three, I think SVN is the most popular choice.

1. Setup your project.
2. Delete the build folder.
3. Setup repository.
4. Import project to repo.
5. Checkout project from repo so you'll get a versioned copy.

Comment: Subversion is indeed probably the most popular of the currently supported SCM systems. You may also want to consider using Git to future-proof yourself.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Starting with Xcode 4, I've also moved to using Git.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first - it is not called *sourcesafe system*, but *version control* - way of controlling evolution of source code and its versioning. *Sourcesafe* is a specific product by Microsoft.

Second - *version control* is data agnostic. That means you can use any system you know. The best tool is the one you know well.

That being said, there are some advantages in using specific *version control* systems as Subversion and Git, because those two are going to be supported in next version of Xcode (version 4).

Current Xcode (version 3) has support for Subversion, CVS and Perforce. If you are familiar with any of these, use them, but do not restrict yourself only to these. Stability of *version control* support in Xcode 3 is mediocre, at least with Subversion which I've used. Xcode 4 is going to be a huge improvement in this area.

Lots of developers, me included, prefer not to use integrated support for *version control* in Xcode (or any other developer tools), but use specific clients - like *Versions* for Subversion, or command-line tools for *Git*.

I want to comment on use of *Git*, which I personally use and love. It is a distributed system, and for beginners its concepts might be a bit hard to grasp. Consider the experience of your teammates when deciding to use it - for lots of teams it's better to use something more traditional like *Subversion*.

Answer (score 0):

SmartCVS is also one of good tool which we use for co working with teammates